# Form Input Field Validation Using Directives

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular-bootstrap, angular-directive-link

I want to apply "ng-pattern" to the form input fields using a directive. Let's say I want to check if the value provided is an integer or not.

form-markup

```
<form class="form" name="frm" novalidate>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Age</label>
    <input int
        type="text"
        name="age"
        class="form-control"
        ng-model="fd.age">
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="frm.age.$error.pattern">
           age is just a number.
        </span>
</div>
</form>
```

and the directive code is like this

```
app.directive("int", function($compile){
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: true,
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.attr("ng-pattern", "/[0-9]+/");
        }
    }
});
```

In the markup I can see that it is applied properly but still it doesn't work. The pattern is correct because when I use it explicitly in the markup without using the directive it works nicely.

I have two questions.

1. Why this doesn't work?
2. Since I have to write a lot of such domain specific directives, is my approach correct to solve this problem pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to incapsulate an existing validator in your custom directive, you should try implementing a custom validation rule as explained in [this article](http://angularjs.io/how-to-create-a-custom-input-validator-with-angularjs/)

I've modified your example using this technique.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/6410/)

Code:

```
<form class="form" name="frm" novalidate>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Age</label>
    <input int
        type="text"
        name="age"
        class="form-control"
        ng-model="fd.age">
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="frm.age.$error.numberValidator">
           age is just a number.
        </span>
</div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
app.directive("int", function() {
      return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: true,
        replace: true,
          require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs,ctrl) {
            function customValidator(ngModelValue) {
    
              if (/^[0-9]+$/.test(ngModelValue)) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('numberValidator', true);
              } else {
                ctrl.$setValidity('numberValidator', false);
              }
              return ngModelValue;
            }
            ctrl.$parsers.push(customValidator);
          }
        }
    });
```

### Update

For your specific case - there is a standard validation rule `$error.number` described in [this documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D)

### Update 2

To answer your first question - for the `ng-pattern` directive to be functional you need to re-run the compile cycle via `$compile` service  for the given element and bind it to the `scope`.
Like this:

```
myApp.directive("int2", function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: true,
    replace: true,
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.attr("ng-pattern", "/^[0-9]+$/");
      elem.removeAttr("int2");
      $compile(elem)(scope); 
    }
  }
});
```

Here is an updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/6412/) to illustrate the behavior.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be a better way since it doesn't require any dom manipulation  in the link function. But I am still hunting for my Q1. If I attach a directive in the link function, then it should simply work.

Comment: something not right here. My browser simply hangs because of this code. The one with $compile and what is elem.removeAttr("int2");

Comment: `elem.removeAttr("int2");` removes the custom directive so it would not be called again after `$compile` is triggered ( which essentially asks angular to evaluate the directives again) to avoid getting in an infinite loop.